# Does "poste restante" require ID in Germany?

Tags: germany, mail

Does German poste restante (aka general delivery, "Postlagernd" in German) require you to show ID to receive package or you can use just password instead?

Comment: Since you can also send "poste restante" to a sort of password [German Mail uses "password:flower69" as their example, I kid you not,](https://www.deutschepost.de/de/p/postlagernd.html) I would assume that no ID is required to pick up the package (otherwise good luck identifying yourself).

Comment: @mts Why not write that as an answer? It might be relevant, that the usage of a password or passphrase as recipient is not allowed for registered mail (in which case you would definitely need an id to pickup the delivery) or for cash/payment on delivery shipments.

Comment: I honestly have never done that and I have 1% doubt that DeutschePost asks you for an ID even if you show up for a password letter. This is no common thing in Germany at all and lesser internet forums give wrong/confusing info, so I'd like to try before posting as an answer @Tor-EinarJarnbjo. Of course someone with more experience is welcome to post an answer before I get around to try these things.

Comment: Note that this is only for letters in the sense of their _AGB Brief_. You're talking about a _package_ in the question. The terms of services for letters include all kinds of, well, letters and postcards as well as small parcels of up to 2kg and dimensions of a maximum of 60 x 30 x 15 cm and _Büchersendungen_ which are the kind of parcel where Amazon sends you a single book. A typical _DHL Paket_ like the average Amazon shipment that does not contain books is not covered by this. But it might work anyway.

Comment: @mts are you going to send yourself a letter?

Answer (score 3):

Seeing that the German "poste restante" allows specifying a password instead of a name on the package, it should certainly be possible to receive a package without an ID check. Rough Google Translate of the [relevant page](https://www.deutschepost.de/de/p/postlagernd.html):

> The receiver's address must be structured as follows:
>
> Name of the addressee **or - in ordinary shipments - even passwords /
>   pseudonyms etc.**
>
> ...
>
> John Doe **or password: Blume69**
>   Postlagernd
>   Münsterplatz 17
>   53111 Bonn

So the answer is **yes**, as long as a password is specified on the package address, rather than a specific name.